# How to serve static file in google vm bucket server?

Tags: web, google-cloud-platform, deployment, backend, makecode

I am using Google cloud for deploying code maker project , And in google cloud i am using Bucket for serving static file (open source -> https://github.com/Microsoft/pxt-maker).
I Follow this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ACifzOIR_Ec&t=504s) ,In my local server i am using -> http-server -c-1 built/packaged for serve static file as it is shown in (https://makecode.com/cli/staticpkg) And it is the output -->
Starting up http-server, serving built/packaged
Available on:
  http://127.0.0.1:8080
  http://192.168.43.179:8080

But when i am using google bucket for serving it shows me an error if i am using (https://storage.googleapis.com/www.makecode.e-textile.in/built/packaged/)

It shows me this

```
  <Error>
<Code>NoSuchKey</Code>
<Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message>
<Details>
No such object: www.makecode.e-textile.in/built/packaged/
</Details>
</Error>
```

And when i am using (https://storage.googleapis.com/www.makecode.e-textile.in/built/packaged/index.html)
It gives me a blank page. 
Any body help me out why this occour.

If there are any other deploy process for deploying this make code project please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to look up your zone makecode.e-textile.in and it point to some other host. You need to first [set up your DNS Zone in Cloud DNS](https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/quickstart)